# Retrofit2 FromUrlEncoded not handling Japanese characters

Tags: java, http, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

When sending POST requests to an API endpoint using `@FormUrlEncoded` from RetroFit2, the record looked scrambled when it was Japanese but ok when English.

The charset was set to null when using to send POST request.
`Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` was the header instead of `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8`

```java
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/items")
Call<ApiResponse> post(@FieldMap Map<String, Object> fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

2 Solutions:

1. add the headers manually for each endpoint, not very scaleable solution

```java
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/items")
@Headers("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")
Call<ApiResponse> post(@FieldMap Map<String, Object> fields);
```

2. add an interceptor to add it for endpoints having POST, a bit more verbose:

```java
    @Bean
    public ApiService apiService(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        final OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(chain -> {
            final Request original = chain.request();
            if (original.method().equals("POST")) {
                final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
                original.body().writeTo(buffer);
                final String content = buffer.readString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                final RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(""application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), content);
                final Request request = original.newBuilder().method(original.method(), body).build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            } else {
                return chain.proceed(original);
            }
        }).build();

        final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(httpClient)
                .baseUrl(apiBaseUrl)
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    }
```